# Use an existing CSS class for hover despite overriding classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm handed a class `.custom-class` which styles elements I'm creating a certain way, but when I hover over the element, other styles take precedence. For example, if I create my element as `<a class="custom-class">...</a>`, it styles appropriately by default; but when I hover over the element, `a:hover` takes effect:

[image: A screenshot of a devtools console showing an active a:hover style and an inactive custom-class style.]

I'm adding this HTML element to a VS code webview, so I don't (or shouldn't) have control over either (1) `a:hover` or (2) the fact that `.custom-class` is a class (likewise, I can't modify the source of the class—it's not *my* `.custom-class`). I *do* have control over the entire HTML element I'm creating, and am creating the element via javascript.

What's the best way to style the element according to `.custom-class` even on hover?

Comment: When making the element, add a `mouseover` event listener that changes the style to the correct color. Add another `mouseleave` event listener to change it back.

Comment: @MrDiamond How do I use the class to get that style? I don't want to be hardcoding colors here. Also that seems awfully low-level...surely there's a better, more CSS-y, way?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't another way to do it without modifying the .custom-class source.

Comment: @MrDiamond Hmm, if modifying the source would work...could I create another class which styles things according to `.custom-class`, but somehow also handles hovers correctly? (I'm really hoping there's a better way out there, but I do have the power to insert style tags in addition to my HTML element if I need to.)

Comment: `.custom-class:hover`

Comment: Sounds like whoever is in control of this project needs to give you more control, or they at least need to add hover styles to the class. This is kind of a crazy situation to be in when the solution is so simple.

Comment: @ralph.m Well, to be fair, this is a big open-source project that is meant to be extensible with widgets (Lean), and I don't think they expected these classes to be used for links initially. :) These *could* be added, it just might be slower than figuring it out on my end.

Comment: Still, it might be worth discussing this with them, as it sounds like it's turning into a bit of a mess. (Not trying to be mean, here, but just worried about things getting out of control.)

Comment: @ralph.m Eh, my little widget being able to use these styles for links isn't so critical; I don't think it's getting out of control. It's not like I'm part of the core development here. But I might see if they'd want to upgrade those classes anyway. :)

Comment: Okay, I was picturing you working on a big site or something like that. Ideally, they'd have a facility for writing custom CSS.

Comment: @ralph.m Ah, yeah—my notion of "big" is probably off! I'm not a programmer by trade. It's certainly bigger than any collaborative project I've worked on academically, but possibly quite small by industry standards. To add some context, there are several moving parts: there's the language itself, then the VS code extension, then the rather niche functionality for creating custom widgets from *within* the language which the extension displays in a webview to the side. And I'm just volunteering contribution (in this case, for a widget) and participating in the community. :)

Comment: @MrDiamond Do you mean a style tag like `<style type="text/css">.custom-class:hover</style>` or possibly `<style type="text/css">.custom-class:hover { .custom-class } </style>`? Neither of those seem to work, but my CSS might be horribly malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this problem should ideally be solved by modifying the actual CSS source, you can use the [CSS Object Model APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model) to iterate document stylesheets and rules to find the desired class name selector, then modify it to also match hovered links with the same class name. Here's a reproducible example:

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgYRSgylAngGwFMAlEIgCgCczCAuRNLLUogSnuqORQaZwJI1EAbwBQiRJUJQQlJJ0IA6CAhRRq0OJUVgAhgFtCiALynEAIkZM8RFoXMBuUQF9Ro4FsTkVYNYhQAFoTSiHDAiAAmcBAghmBQimoCWEHSKKwi4ogelF4+fgqh4YHBCRCYdumZEhIw4eRZNdwY2DaCFAqsjTUAZD2SNImERJqUACqEAB5QJmbmyiBqcPoAtBD4upjm3RkKQyNQWhPTJhYLS6vrmygANIi654eXG5i0AXAAboSUjlmurkA)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <title>so-76965389</title>

  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #000000;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    a:hover {
      color: #0000ff;
    }
  </style>

  <!--
    The following data URL, when decoded, looks like this:

    .custom-class {
      color: #ffcc00;
    }
  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="data:text/css;base64,LmN1c3RvbS1jbGFzcyB7CiAgY29sb3I6ICNmZmNjMDA7Cn0=" />
  <script type="module">
    function isCssStyleRule(rule) {
      return rule.constructor.name === "CSSStyleRule";
    }

    function modifySelector() {
      for (const sheet of document.styleSheets) {
        for (const rule of sheet.cssRules) {
          if (
            isCssStyleRule(rule)
            && rule.selectorText === ".custom-class"
          ) {
            rule.selectorText = ".custom-class, a.custom-class:hover";
          }
        }
      }
    }

    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
      modifySelector();
      ev.currentTarget.remove();
    }, { once: true });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a class="custom-class" href="#">Link</a>
  <button>Modify selector</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If — instead of modifying the existing rule — you want to create a new rule to duplicate its styles with a new selector, you can use the [CSSStyleRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule) documentation to inform your approach.

Comment: Oh, this looks very promising, thank you! (I have to run for now, but if this works when I get back and have the chance to try it, I'll accept the answer. :) )

Answer (score 0):

You can add a local stylesheet that's loaded later to override the `a:hover` behavior by defining `a:hover` to behave in the way you want.

Another way to do it is by increasing CSS specifity.

[CSS specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 0):

```css
a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.custom-class {
  color: orange;
}

a.custom-class:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="custom-class">a with custom-class</a>
<br>
<a href="#">Just a</a>
```